# Add a list as a property of an object

Tags: c#, arrays, list, object

Having an array of objects like this:

```
List<object> myArray = new List<object>();

myArray = [{name = "abc", id = 1},
           {name = "xxx", id = 2},
           {name = "abc", id = 3},
    ];
```

I want that if there are more objects having the same name to combine them into one object and save the ids into a list. For the above array the desired result should be something like:

```
myArray = [{name = "abc", (id = 1, id = 3)},
           {name = "xxx", id = 2},
    ];
```

Maybe it is not the best way to do it like this. I would like to find out any useful suggestions.

Comment: do you have an array of anonymous objects? Did you think about creating a class to represent it? It would be really cool if you would post compilable code

Comment: it is `List<object> myArray = new List<object>();`

Comment: I assume after your edit you have to use reflection in order to get the values of your objects, as `object` doesn´t know *anythibng* about your actual names.

Comment: please edit the rest of the code also. post the real code please. it seems that you are hiding the anonymous objects inside `object`

Comment: I don't know if the real code helps, I tried to put only the essential, but this is the whole code: https://pastebin.com/6hzLCsmh

Comment: although I would advise to make a custom class to represent the type, you could use `dynamic` instead of `object`. this way you can use the solution by @HimBromBeere. But the disclaimer remains: rather create a custom class. which has already a `List<int> Ids` to save the `alertBinding.SiteId`

Comment: thanks, I will try to do it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just group your data based on the `Name`-property:

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => new 
    { 
        Name = x.Key, 
        Ids = x.Select(y => y.id).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Didn´t you mention in the comment your list is of an anoymopus type having `Name` and `Id`_properties? You should definitly provide your actual code to show your data-structure to avoid this kind of misunderstandings. And please aedit your question appropriately, don´t add a comment.

Comment: @LeoMessi how do you then initiate the `name` and `id` properties ? like this: `new { name = "abc", id = 1},`